# Change ZIndex of images in a flatlist

Tags: react-native, image, z-index, react-native-flatlist

I am having serious problems changing the Zindex of images in my flatlist. Its works fine to start with but when I have clicked on an image, I add animation to it and it moves the images and changes a couple of things. The problem is, is that I need the center image to be in front of the other 2.

Here are images of how it looks before click and after.

Before:

[image]

After:
[image]

As you see they have animated to how I want them. The code is quite long so will just add the main bits.

This is the Flatlist itself:

```
<Animated.FlatList
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={movies}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
        extraData={activeItem}
        horizontal
        bounces={false}
        CellRendererComponent={({children}) => children}
        scrollEnabled={enableScroll}
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
        decelerationRate={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 0.98}
        renderToHardwareTextureAndroid
        contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
        snapToInterval={ITEM_SIZE}
        snapToAlignment="start"
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: false }
        )}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          if (!item.poster) {
            return <View style={{ width: EMPTY_ITEM_SIZE }} />;
          }
```

This is how I display the images in it :

```
{activeItem === index && (
                <EntryAnimation
                  index={1}
                  action={selected}
                  rotateV={0}
                  scaleV={0.8}
                  offsetXV={0}
                  offsetYX={0}>
                  <Animated.Image
                    source={{ uri: item.poster }}
                    style={[styles.posterImage, { zIndex: 999 }]}
                  />
                </EntryAnimation>
              )}
```

I have tried changing the index in the animations but it stays the same. I have read about CellRendererComponent but I cannot find out very much about it and I have tried adding this to the flatlist but again nothing changes.

Anyone got any ideas or am I going about it the wrong way?

Thanks